# On sets of coprime numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, asymptotics

We know that from prime number theorem that the number of primes below $n$ and above $\frac n2$ (denoted by $\pi_{n,\frac n2}$ is approximately $$\pi_{n,\frac n2}\approx\frac{n}{2\ln n}.$$

Denote by $\mathcal R_{c,n,d}$ as the sets of coprime numbers below $n$ and above $\frac n2$ with each set of cardinality $c$ such that any pair of sets overlap at atmost $d$ integers.

**(1)** What does the function $f(c,n,d)=|\mathcal R_{c,n,d}|$ look like?

**(2)** Is there a sharp estimate to $k_n>0$ such that $f\Big(\pi_{n,\frac n2},n,\frac{\pi_{n,\frac n2}}{k}\Big)>\pi_{n,\frac n2}$ at every $k<k_n$?